# Why does the duplicates array not receive the second value of the nums array?

Tags: javascript

```js
function duplicateNumbers(nums) {
  let unique = {};
  let duplicates = [];
  for (let i = 0; i < nums.length; i++) {
    if (!unique[nums[i]]) {
      unique[nums[i]] = i;
    } else {
      if (duplicates.indexOf(nums[i]) == -1) {
        duplicates.push(nums[i]);
      }
    }
  }
  return duplicates;
}
console.log(duplicateNumbers([1, 1, 5, 5, 5, 5, 7, 5, 3, 3, 3]))
```

Why does the duplicates array not receive the second value of the nums array?

```
// delivered output: [5,3]
// expected output: [1,5,3]
```

Comment: `unique[nums[i]] = i;` should be `unique[nums[i]] = true` or the `if(!unique[nums[i]])` should be `if(unique[nums[i]]!== undefined)`

Comment: You're storing an index in `unique`. It's going to be zero for the first unique item. Your `if (!unique[nums[i]])` test is therefore incorrect.

Answer (score 0):

It is because the way you checking for key of the object is wrong. If the value at that key is `0` still you get result as false so better compare the value to `undefined`

```
if (unique[nums[i]] === undefined)
```

```js
function duplicateNumbers(nums) {
  let unique = {};
  let duplicates = [];
  for (let i = 0; i < nums.length; i++) {
    if (unique[nums[i]] === undefined) {
      unique[nums[i]] = i;
    } else {
      if (duplicates.indexOf(nums[i]) == -1) {
        duplicates.push(nums[i]);
      }
    }
  }
  return duplicates;
}
console.log(duplicateNumbers([1, 1, 5, 5, 5, 5, 7, 5, 3, 3, 3]))
```

Answer (score 0):

It is skipping the second item due to a small mistake while adding index to the unique object

`unique[nums[i]] = i;`

In first itration the i becomes `0` and
unique will be like `unique = {1: 0}`

and at the second iteration `if (!unique[nums[i]])` becames false becase of `0`

check the updated solution

```js
function duplicateNumbers(nums) {
  let unique = {};
  let duplicates = [];
  for (let i = 0; i < nums.length; i++) {
    if (!unique[nums[i]]) {
      unique[nums[i]] = true;
    } else {
      if (duplicates.indexOf(nums[i]) == -1) {
        duplicates.push(nums[i]);
      }
    }
  }
  return duplicates;
}
console.log(duplicateNumbers([1, 1, 5, 5, 5, 5, 7, 5, 3, 3, 3]))
```